# How do I get multiple "THEN" results from a Case expression?

Tags: sql, case

First, I am thinking that I cannot do what I originally set out to do, so if there are any suggestions that move away from a case expression, I am open to it.

As simple as I can make it, here is what I want it to look like.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_CRR
WHERE (QTR in ('1st Quarter', '2nd Quarter'))
```

However, I want to supply the filter from a single parameter so that when I select:

```
"1st Quarter" it gives nothing, 
"2nd Quarter" returns "1st Quarter", 
"3rd Quarter" returns both "1st Quarter" and "2nd Quarter" and 
"4th Quarter" returns "3rd Quarter", "2nd Quarter", and "1st Quarter".
```

This is what I have.

```
@QuarterSelect VarChar(15)

AS

SET @QuarterSelect = Case 
                    WHEN @QuarterSelect = '4th Quarter' THEN '3rd Quarter'
                    WHEN @QuarterSelect = '4th Quarter' THEN '2nd Quarter'
                    WHEN @QuarterSelect = '4th Quarter' THEN '1st Quarter'
                    WHEN @QuarterSelect = '3rd Quarter' THEN '2nd Quarter'
                    WHEN @QuarterSelect = '3rd Quarter' THEN '1st Quarter'
                    WHEN @QuarterSelect = '2nd Quarter' THEN '1st Quarter'
                    WHEN @QuarterSelect = '1st Quarter' THEN ''
                    ELSE '' 
                  END

SELECT *
FROM Table_CRR
WHERE (QTR in (@QuarterSelect))
```

It obviously terminates and only gives me '2nd Quarter'. I am sure there is a elegant way to do this, I am just having trouble figuring it out.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Example of what I want to see: When I set the @QuarterSelect parameter to '3rd Quarter'

```
|Key    |Qtr        |
---------------------
|772384 |1st Quarter|
|407038 |1st Quarter|
|790033 |1st Quarter|
|188914 |1st Quarter|
|1607947|2nd Quarter|
|1683954|2nd Quarter|
|1607937|2nd Quarter|
|1948397|2nd Quarter|
...
```

Comment: a `CASE` expression is scalar, it returns only one result per row

Comment: is `QTR` a column in the table? or do you have a `date` column in the table?

Comment: Lamak -  That is what I am finding. I dont know how to do this otherwise.

vkp - Quarter is a VarChar column in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might be over simplifying, but if your strings are consistent, then why not just do a compare for less than.

```
SELECT *
   FROM Table_CRR
   WHERE 
      QTR < '1st Quarter'   -- returns nothing, unless you have something else   

SELECT *
   FROM Table_CRR
   WHERE 
      QTR < '2st Quarter'   -- returns 1st since 1 is less than 2 string compare

SELECT *
   FROM Table_CRR
   WHERE 
      QTR < '3rd Quarter'   -- returns 1st and 2nd since 1 & 2 are less than 3 string compare

SELECT *
   FROM Table_CRR
   WHERE 
      QTR < '4th Quarter'   -- returns 1st, 2nd and 3rd since 1, 2 & 3 are less than 4 string compare
```

Comment: HA! Man, its always the KISS principal isn't it? This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little crude, but if all of your `QTR` labels have the same structure, you could use the first digit such that your query looks like:

```
declare @QuarterSelect int = 3

SELECT *
FROM Table_CRR
WHERE (cast(left(QTR,1) as int) < (@QuarterSelect))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confused about how variables work.  A fariable can only have *one* value, so to try to set it to *two* values does not make sense.  I *think* you want something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_CRR
WHERE (@QuarterSelect = '3rd Quarter' AND QTR in ('1st Quarter', '2nd Quarter')) OR
      (@QuarterSelect = {next option} AND QTR in ({other options}))
```

Or create an in-memory mapping table and `join` to it:

```
DECLARE @OptionsMap TABLE
(
    OPTION VARCHAR(15),
    QTR    VARCHAR(15)
)

INSERT INTO @OptionsMap
VALUES ('4th Quarter' , '3rd Quarter')
INSERT INTO @OptionsMap
VALUES ('4th Quarter' ,'2nd Quarter')
INSERT INTO @OptionsMap
VALUES ('4th Quarter' ,'1st Quarter')
INSERT INTO @OptionsMap
VALUES ('3rd Quarter' ,'2nd Quarter')
INSERT INTO @OptionsMap
VALUES ('3rd Quarter' ,'1st Quarter')
INSERT INTO @OptionsMap
VALUES ('2nd Quarter' ,'1st Quarter')
INSERT INTO @OptionsMap
VALUES ('1st Quarter' , '')

SELECT *
FROM Table_CRR
WHERE QTR IN (SELECT QTR FROM @OptionsMap WHERE Option = @QuarterSelect)
```

Comment: Right, and when I do standard queries I follow what you said.

I am wanting my Parameter to supply the filter when I select a specific quarter.

I worry I am being confusing. I am going to add an example of what I want to see.

Comment: So you either need a table that maps one option to your filter values or use chained statements like I have in my answer.  There's not a way to store multiple values in a single scalar variable or to return multiple values from a `CASE` statement.

Comment: That was a thought I had. Create a small table that maps each parameter selection to the values I want to filter with.

Comment: @J Lyne - no, you're creating a single scalar variable, not a table.  You can create a table variable and `INSERT` values into it, but it's not as compact as what you're trying to do now.

Answer (score 1):

I see the solution is already accepted, but to the context of the question the following is also considerable.

```
SET @QuarterSelect=
Case 
                    WHEN @QuarterSelect = '4th Quarter' THEN '''3rd Quarter'',''2nd Quarter'',''1st Quarter'''

                    WHEN @QuarterSelect = '3rd Quarter' THEN '''2nd Quarter'',''1st Quarter'''

                    WHEN @QuarterSelect = '2nd Quarter' THEN '''1st Quarter'''

                    ELSE ''

                  END

                  declare @sql nvarchar(max);
set @sql = 'SELECT * FROM Table_CRR WHERE (QTR in (' + @QuarterSelect + ')';
exec sp_executesql @sql
```